# Is it possible to simulate stereo audio in one channel?

Tags: stereo, hearing-damage

Becoming (recently) deaf in one ear, I really miss listening to stereo music properly.

So my question is, is it is possible to listen to 2 channel (stereo) music, with an effect reasonably similar stereo, in one channel?

By my understanding, the stereo effect is a matter of phase shifting the second channel, but I have never heard of such an application (though I hadn't reason to consider such a thing until recently).

So I am looking for an electronics design or method where I can input stereo audio and get a similar sounding output in one channel.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily deliver stereo-like effect on a mono channel by pan-pot, but then you'd face two major problems:

- The result is reasonable with non-rhythmic tracks, e.g., recording of talks, but it is quite poor when it comes to music, particularly when the music's beat is highly accented.
- You'd probably still need directionality in order for the brain to interpret the sensory input as stereophonic, and that might a problem in the case of a single-sided impairment.

What you might want to try instead is to use a bone conductive transducer such as [SoundBite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SoundBite_Hearing_System), its applicability though in your specific case needs to be consulted with a relevant practitioner.

Comment: A good idea, but in my case it is vestibular nerve damage so one side is all I have to go on. As you say, a true stereo effect probably requires mental interpretation, but new techniques are developed all the time.